# RegEx match sequence of three strings along with text inbetween

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression to match something inbetween two strings that includes a third. I'm having trouble getting the lazy quantifier to cooperate, as there are multiple instances of these strings in the input and the RegEx matches something that is not useful, i.e.:

`Start...End...Start...End...Start...Middle...End`

Whet I'm actually looking for (only one instance of Start and End for each match):

`Start...Middle...End` or `Start...Center...End`

I'm pretty sure I need to use lookahead/lookbehind, but while I do conceptually understand them, putting them into practice is really difficult. Here's where I'm at:

`/<Start[\s\S]*?(Middle|Center)[\s\S]*?End>/gm`

Comment: Just a slight modification would allow your regex to work: `Start[\s\S]*?(Middle|Center)?[\s\S]*?End` - I made `(Middle|Center)?` optional. I would use `\bStart\b.*?(Middle|Center)?.*?\bEnd\b` instead though and turn on the `s` modifier (dot matches newline). Also note it uses `\b` so that you don't accidentally catch something else like `Endow`

Comment: You have added four tags ([tag:java], [tag:c#], [tag:python] and [tag:perl]) which have nothing to do with your question.  We take tags seriously on this site, and we ask that you only tag what your question is about.  I have since removed them.

Comment: Sorry about that, won't happen again.

@ctwheels Matching the string in the middle is mandatory, so unfortunately that doesn't cut it.

Comment: @Cake4 my apologies, I misunderstood your question. Wiktor got it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
Start(?:(?!Start|End)[\s\S])*?(Middle|Center)[\s\S]*?End
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P6HS1q/2)

**Details**

- `Start` - a literal string
- `(?:(?!Start|End)[\s\S])*?` - any char, 0+ repetitions, as few as possible, that is not a starting point of `Start` or `End` sequence
- `(Middle|Center)` - Group 1: `Middle` or `Center`
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `End`  - a literal string

Comment: Thank you very much! I looked for quite a while, but it looks like I wasn't able to formulate my question correctly. This explanation clears it up a bit better for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40999431/8941643